# What are the differences between Ranorex and TestComplete if there is any

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex, testcomplete

I have been working on a test automation project. My customer is considering both Ranorex and test complete as potential test suites, can I ask if there is any difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal opinions, please take them with a grain of salt.

TestComplete vs Ranorex:

Key differences:

### User interface

- Ranorex has object mapping and test steps displayed on the same page.
- TestComplete has object mapping and test steps on different pages.

### Test execution

- Ranorex moves around mouse cursor in a more realistic way, e.g. you can see mouse cursor moving.
- Ranorex types a string by a character at a time.
- Ranorex has dynamic-wait built into its keywords.
- Ranorex opens a console window that displays debugging logs in real time
- TestComplete teleports mouse cursor around without a trace.
- TestComplete copies and pastes a string instantly.
- TestComplete does not have dynamic-wait built into its keywords.
- TestComplete provides minimum debugging logs during test execution.

### Validation

- Only Ranorex provides validation Actions that verifies a chosen object's attributes.
- TestComplete does not offer any similar function, although it can be scripted to accomplish the same.

### Development IDE

- Ranorex has a development IDE very similar to Visual Studio, it
  offers smart keyword matching, refactoring and etc.
- TestComplete does not have an IDE, its support is very limited.

### Language support

- TestComplete supports Javascript, C#Script and other scripting
  languages. C#Script is a C# dialect.
- Ranorex supports C#, Python and etc. C# is a more powerful and more structured language.

### Test result reporting

- Ranorex test result reporting is more comprehensive, it offers
  information about previous and current test runs in Pie Charts
- TestComplete only offers test report on current test runs.

### Cost

- Ranorex is cheaper than TestComplete.

Comment: Having working with testcomplete for long time let me add more to above.. "TestComplete teleports mouse cursor"-this could be configure with speed as you wish. "TestComplete copies and pastes a string instantly" -you can configure this as well to type one letter at a time. "TestComplete does not have an IDE" - it has but very limited compaired to visual studio or eclipse. Test complete now support Python,dhelphy script, vbscript, c++script. Test complete is not cheap

Answer (score 1):

Things must have changed a lot with TestComplete since 2017. Everything must have changed with TestComplete since 2017. Testcomplete has always had an IDE and it's a very good IDE. Easy to move around in and very VS like. Huge community and free video learning. So far I've tried Tosca, UFT, TestComplete and Ranorex for evaluation and only TestComplete was able to pass the first software evaluation test I ran them all though.

Answer (score 1):

Ranorex and Test Complete are two of the most popular tools used by QA testers. However, most of the time, test complete is preferred by testers for meeting the requirements of the tests. Though Ranorex offers an easier to understand initial setup with user guide, Test Complete offers much more robustness to QA testers. On the other hand, Ranorax even has very limited language support and needs a paid license to use whereas test complete offers easier setup and features like built-in pdf reading support.